# Add current user (read) to contributor permission group on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, csom

I want to add current user(read) to contributor permission group on page load but below code is alerting 'undefined':

```
var user;
var spGroup;
function AddUserToSharePointGroup() {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

var siteGroups = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
spGroup=siteGroups.getById(7);
user=clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
//alert(user.email);
var userCollection=spGroup.get_users();
userCollection.addUser(user);
clientContext.load(user);
clientContext.load(spGroup);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
alert('success');
}

function onQueryFailed() {
alert('Request failed.');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below mentioned code is used to add user to SharePoint group. You will get idea from below mentioned sample code.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
    public void AddUserToDMSite(string useremail, string securityGroupName, Web aWeb)
            {
                GroupCollection collGroup = aWeb.SiteGroups;
                Group oGroup2 = collGroup.GetByName(securityGroupName);
                UserCollection oUserCollection2 = oGroup2.Users;
                SPContext.Load(oUserCollection2);
                SPContext.ExecuteQuery();
                //Get Current user in below line. I have fetched it by email ID                
                var uname = oGroup1.Users.GetByEmail(useremail);
                var userCheck = oUserCollection2.Where(u => u.Email == useremail).FirstOrDefault();
                if (userCheck == null)
                {
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.User oUser2 = oGroup2.Users.AddUser(uname);
                }
                SPContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

I hope it helps you...

Comment: can u tell me what to be replaced in place of securityGroupName and userlist

Comment: securityGroupName means the Group where you want to add the user. UserList is the main user information list from where it finds the email id & check whether the user is available or not.

Comment: Please check the updated code...

Comment: its not working

Comment: is it throwing same error?

Comment: You need to pass credential of power user in client context as User with read permission can not add users in SharePoint group.

Comment: its showing " ; " missing at         :                                                                                         public void AddUserToDMSite(string useremail, string securityGroupName, Web aWeb)
            {
                GroupCollection collGroup = aWeb.SiteGroups; god knows from where the hell , this is generating error is coming

Comment: Remove User check lines & try it again.

Comment: Have you tried it? If it works for you than i can change my answer accordingly

Comment: user check lines???

Comment: it seems to be server site code...need csom

Comment: Whatever code do you use but You need to pass credential of power user in client context because **User with read permission can not add himself\herself in SharePoint group**.